# A characterization of continuity in terms of preservation of connected sets. Where to find the result?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, continuity

There is a result that if $X$ is a locally connected space and $Y$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, then a function $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f$ has a closed graph and for every connected set $C \subset X$ the image $f(C)$ is connected.

Although it is not so difficult to prove this, I thought that this was something new so submitted to a journal, and got the reply that this can be found in the literature. The problem is, that email is lost, and I cannot find any article/book online that contains this result. Does anyone know where I can find this and related results? Thank you.

Comment: Look at  [W.J. Pervin, N. Levine, Connected mappings of Hausdorff spaces, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 9 (1958) 488–496] and [T. Tanaka, On the family of connected subsets and the topology of spaces, J. Math. Soc. Japan 7 (1955),
389–393]. Maybe it is not exactly what you need, but at least related.

Answer (score 2):

This characterisation, at least for real valued functions of one real variable, is quite popular in some didactic traditions, because it gives quite a clear visual picture of continuity (although not immediately practical): A function is continuous if and only if you can draw the graph without lifting the pen. Consequently there are a number of papers treating the subject (though I'm not sure if in the full generality of your result) and giving  proofs of the equivalence especially for didactic purposes.
A short google search gives e.g.

[*Continuous Functions and Connected Graphs*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324521#metadata_info_tab_contents), C. E. Burgess (The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 97, No. 4 (Apr., 1990), pp. 337-339.

[*“A function is continuous if and only if you can draw its graph without lifting the pen from the paper” – Concept usage in proofs by students in a topology course*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338769776_A_function_is_continuous_if_and_only_if_you_can_draw_its_graph_without_lifting_the_pen_from_the_paper_-_Concept_usage_in_proofs_by_students_in_a_topology_course), E.Hanke (Second conference of the INDRUM, International Network for Didactic Research in University Mathematics, 2018)